# Gnuplot out of memory

Tags: memory-management, gnuplot

I am working on drawing graphs with Gnuplot.
The thing is as it works on, due to high memeory usage, it does not work properly, or be killed in a few minutes.

My laptops memory is 4GB. And the file size if around 1GB to 1.5 GB.
Actually, I am a beginner of C language and gnuplotting. What I cannot understand is that why this 'simple-looking' work takes so many memories. It's just matching points of t and x between.

I'll write down a part of the file below. And the code I wrote down on the terminal was;

```
plot "fl1.dat" u 1:2 linetype 1.
```

1.00000e+00 1.88822e-01

2.00000e+00 3.55019e-01

3.00000e+00 -1.74283e+00

4.00000e+00 -2.67627e+00

...

...

...

Is only way I can do is add more RAM, or using computer on lab?

Thank you.

Comment: How many data points do you have? 32 bit system or 32 bit gnuplot?

Comment: The system is 64 bit. And I'm not so sure about gnuplot. How can I check it? And then, the data points are 4e7.

Comment: When starting gnuplot it tells you the Build System. I do also get an out of memory error with the 32bit build when plotting such a huge file. The 64bit build plots the data, but starts swapping do disk, depending on the used output terminal. BTW: What do you expect to see from 40 million data points?

Comment: My gnuplot is 64 built. I re-checked. Actually, I have no sense at all. I just cannot understand what takes it so many memories and time. For me, it seems like really simple works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing to note is that the choice of [output terminal](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node341.html) can have a tremendous effect on the memory consumption: interactive windows or vector formats will consume *much* more (I guess because these formats keep track of every single data-point, even though, as stressed by Peaceful, you probably don't need all those points). So a quick way to reduce the memory consumption may be to set the output terminal to a modestly-sized png, eg:

```
set terminal png size 1000,1000
set output "mygraph.png"
```

Answer (score 3):

Plotting of a data file is done to see the overall or global behavior of some quantity, not the local behavior for which you can just see the value from the data file. This, said, in your case, I think you do not need to plot each and every point from the file since the file is huge and it seems pointless to plot it all. Thus I suggest the following:

```
pl 'fl1.dat' u 1:2 every 10
```

This will plot every 10'th point only but if anyway there are two many points spaced very finely, then that would still show a global behavior of the plot nicely. Remember that this won't connect the individual points. If you still want a continuous line, I suggest to create another data file with every 10th file in it and then plot it as usual with lines.